# What if I give the pointer just a normal value

Tags: c, pointers, ascii

This is a normal code in c language

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char *a;
  a = "H";
  printf("%d",*a);
}
```

When I run the code I get the value of char `a` with `%s`. But with `%d` I get `72`. What does this value `72` mean?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Be sure to take the
[tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the [help
center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). [Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) is an overview of all format specifiers for `printf` and related functions. You might find it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the character code for the `H` character. It's similar to doing:

```
char c = 'H';
printf("%d\n", c);
```